# Linq - 2 Columns Not Condition

Tags: sql, linq

I am trying query where i want Records that are Not in 2 Columns.
To simplify my issue, below is simple example where i want first 2 records to be selected as per below query.

It gives me 0 records in result.

```
    var data = ctx.tblIncrement.Where(m => m.EmployeeID == 1388 && m.EffectiveDate == '2019-04-01'
 && !(m.ApplyMonth == 12 && m.ApplyYear == 2019)).ToList();
```

[image: Lin]

Can you help me how to use 2 Columns Not condition.

Comment: Does it work if you get rid of the date clause in your query? Try it out just as an experiment. At first glance, I see nothing else wrong with your query.

Comment: You are comparing string `m.EffectiveDate == '2019-04-01'` while in sql containt time part.

Comment: can you try something like this (m.ApplyMonth != 12 && m.ApplyYear == 2019) instead of !(m.ApplyMonth == 12 && m.ApplyYear == 2019)

Comment: @Anup, your using `m.ApplyYear ` as not equal to 2019. So, only ur not getting any records.

Comment: `m.EffectiveDate == '2019-04-01'` is invalid C# code, which makes your question very confusing as to which data types are involved.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing string `m.EffectiveDate == '2019-04-01'` while in sql contains time part.

You can try this way to achieve it, (Keep in mind re-design `EffectiveDate` type form `string` to `DateTime` instead):

```
var dateToCompare = new DateTime(2019, 04, 01);
var data = ctx.tblIncrement.Where(m => m.EmployeeID == 1388 && m.EffectiveDate == dateToCompare
 && !(m.ApplyMonth == 12 && m.ApplyYear == 2019)).ToList();
```